# Why Unity3d doesn't support plane casting? Is there a way to implement own one or use some plugin/library?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I hadn't found any way to quickly detect collisions of an object with a plane. I mean the plane in mathematical terms, that is presented in Unity as `UnityEngine.Plane` class. There are `UnityEngine.Physics.Raycast(...)`, `UnityEngine.Physics.BoxCast(...)`, `UnityEngine.Physics.SphereCast(...)` and so on. But there is no `PlaneCast(...)` or something. Speaking about math, it is well-optimizable algorithm(if you have an access to the physics engine pipeline)

Does Unity have some workaround for it? Or maybe there is a way to "invade" into untiy physics engine pipeline and add such functionality? Or some additional plugins or libraries can be used for this?

Comment: How does a boxcast not forfill the requirement?

Comment: Wouldn't a box with two infinite sides and one really flat side be equivalent to a "Planecast"?